# OS Threads in a Go Program

Tags: go, goroutine

I am using go 1.3.3.
I am trying to understand when Go spawns new threads. I have the following two Go programs:

Program 1:

```
package main

func main() {
     for ;; {
     }
}
```

Program 2:

```
package main
import (
         "sync"
)

func justrun(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
     for ;; {
     }
     wg.Done()
}

func main() {
     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     go justrun(&wg)
     wg.Wait()
}
```

In the activity Monitor I see that for Program 1 there are 2 threads and for Program 2 there are 3 threads. I have multiple questions:

1. In Program 1 what are these 2 threads. I guess one is for "main", but what is the other one for?
2. In Program 2, once i introduce wg.Wait() the number of threads became 3. I was predicting Program 2 to use the same number of threads as Program 1. My understanding is that assume that main() is running on a thread M1 with context P1. The goroutine will go into the runqueue of P1.
   I read somewhere that all primitives in sync package do not cause the goroutine to use a thread when it gets blocked because of them. If this is the case, then goroutine should run concurrently with main in P1 context and on M1 and there should be no need of a new thread. Is wg.Wait() a thread blocking call?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In program 1 the other thread you're seeing is most probably the concurrent garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are that go will spawn exactly `GOMAXPROCS` threads for *user-level* code. From the [runtime](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) documentation:

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads
>   that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously.

But note:

> There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in
>   system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the
>   GOMAXPROCS limit.

The rest is up to the runtime, and is implementation (and version) specific. There are also probably more goroutines running than you may realize; see [What are the three background goroutines in a Go program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747970/what-are-the-three-background-goroutines-in-a-go-program)